# Changing values in database, where updated values might conflict with old values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to update the author ID of all rows in a table (it happens to be authors in a WordPress wp_posts table).

If I want to change author ID 1 -> 10 I can do that with:-

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 10 WHERE post_author = 1;
```

(note - in practice I would use the $wpdb class, but that's the underlying SQL, and the user ID's are just examples - I can't assume anything about what the actual ID's will be).

That update works fine. However, if in the original data set I already have an author ID=10, and I need to update that author to, say ID=20, then I run into trouble - I've already changed all ID=1 to ID=10, so doing the same update again would set ID=20 for all posts who originally had author ID=10 and ID=1.

I could solve the problem using a set of temporary IDs, for example:-

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 90010 WHERE post_author = 1;
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 90020 WHERE post_author = 10;
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 10 WHERE post_author = 90010;
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 20 WHERE post_author = 90020;
```

but that feels ugly, and while I am probably safe choosing some suitably high range for the temporary values, I really ought to check they don't exist first which makes the whole process even more convoluted.

Is there a more elegant way around this?

Comment: Do you have any basis of changing 1 to 10 and 10 to 20? What's the logic behind?

Comment: No those are just examples - in the real case, the user ID's could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated that the *user ID's could be anything*, what I seem to be the elegant way of doing this would be:

1. Create a dummy column (like `dummyUserID` or `_userId` or `previousUserId`). Of course, whatever you want.
2. Update the `userId` to the new column added

   `UPDATE wp_posts SET old_post_author = post_author;`
3. Then that's the trick, do your `UPDATE` using the newly added column.

   `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 90010 WHERE old_post_author = 1;`

   `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 90020 WHERE old_post_author = 10;`

   `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 10 WHERE old_post_author = 90010;`

   `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 20 WHERE old_post_author = 90020;`

Comment: Adding a dummy column certainly has the advantage of not needing to change the IDs to a temporary value (so in your code I could go straight to e.g. `post_author=10 where old_post_author=1`), but adding a column to a table just to do a one off operation still doesn't feel particularly elegant IMHO... even though I could drop the column immediately after so there's no lasting effect.

Comment: Well, I can't think of other ways because `user ID's could be anything`. There will be no computation to be solved.